# Grouping text node and adjacent elements of particular type

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Please suggest, how to group the text node and some elements like '`i`' or '`b`' or '`list`' within '`p`' element. Ensuring `div` should not child to `p`.

**XML:** (with line breaks or whitespaces for display purpose, to run use below 2nd XML)

```
<article>
<body>
    <para>
        <display><fig>Fig1</fig></display>
        the text node1
    </para>
    <para>
        <display><fig>Fig1</fig></display>
    </para>
    <para>
        <display><fig>Fig1</fig></display>
        the text node1 <i>h</i> ther <b>b</b> the text4
        <display><tab>Table1</tab></display>
        the text node2
        <list><li>list1</li></list>
    </para>
    <para>The text node3</para>

</body>
</article>
```

**XML:** (without line breaks)

```
<article><body><para><display><fig>Fig1</fig></display>the text node1</para><para><display><fig>Fig1</fig></display></para><para><display><fig>Fig1</fig></display>the text node1 <i>h</i> ther <b>b</b> the text4<display><tab>Table1</tab></display>the text node2<list><li>list1</li></list></para><para>The text node3</para></body></article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="not(text())"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="display and text() or *">
            <xsl:for-each select="node()">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="name()='display'"><div><xsl:apply-templates/></div></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="name()='i' or name()='b'">
                        <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="not(*)"><p><xsl:value-of select="."/></p></xsl:when><!--Here grouping required with adjacent elements 'i' or 'b' etc -->
                    <xsl:otherwise><p><xsl:apply-templates/></p></xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p><xsl:apply-templates/></p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Required Result:**

```
<article>
<body>
    <div><fig>Fig1</fig></div><!--ensure div should not child to 'p'-->
    <p>the text node1</p>       <!--Text area including 'i' and 'b' to be within 'p' -->
    <div><fig>Fig1</fig></div>
    <div><fig>Fig1</fig></div>
    <p>the text node1 <i>h</i> ther <b>b</b> the text4</p><!--Text area including 'i' and 'b' to be within 'p' -->
    <div><tab>Table1</tab></div>
    <p>the text node2<list><li>list1</li></list></p><!--text area includes 'list' element -->
    <p>The text node3</p>
</body>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are using XSLT 2.0, you can make use of `xsl:for-each-group` here, to group adjacent child nodes depending on whether they are `display` element or not.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::display)">
```

So, the nodes other than `display` will have a grouping key of `false` and so be grouped together, allowing you to wrap them in a `p` tag

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::display)">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
           <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
            </p>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="display">
   <div>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
   </div>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice suggestion, plus one.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `for-each-group group-adjacent="boolean(self::text() | self::i |.."`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="para">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node()" group-adjacent="boolean(self::text() | self::i | self::b | self::list)">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                    <p>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="display">
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, plus one.